# Generate bash shell script or python code for convert data in single row

Tags: python, shell

Suppose I have 3 data corresponding with 3 persons.

Each person have 3 txt files data of the form (variable,value|...),

---

**1.txt**

```
A,10| 

B,11|

C,12|

D,13|

E,14|F,15|G,16|H,17|

I,18|J,19|K,20|L,21|
```

---

**2.txt**

```
M,22|

N,23|

O,24|

P,25|

Q,26|R,27|S,28|T,29|

U,30|V,31|W,32|X,33|
```

---

**3.txt**

```
Y,34|

Z,35|

AA,36|

AB,37|

AC,38|AD,39|AE,40|AF,41|

AG,42|AH,43|AI,44|AJ,45|
```

---

In the same way for the other persons
Convert in excel file

[picture show result after converted in excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3wPH.png)

Comment: Suppose you've already written some code to try to solve this, how would that code look? Please provide an actual description of where you're stuck, and the code you've already tried, and why it doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: If you are just trying to extract all positive integers into a single line separated by commas `grep -hPo '[0-9]+' [123].txt | paste -sd, -`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done quite easily in Bash into a csv

`cat [123].txt | tr -d '[A-Z,][:space:]' | tr "|" "," > /tmp/output.csv`

And now a short explanation:

1. `cat [123].txt` just outputs the text in the files sequentially.
2. The "|" pipes the output of the previous command to the next one. It is immensely useful and very worth getting to know if you intend to use Bash scripting even a little.
3. `tr -d '[A-Z,][:space:]'` deletes all capital letters and commas, as well as any and all spaces and invisible characters such as new line or line break.
4. `tr "|" ","` translates the "|" character to a "," character.
5. And finally `> /tmp/output.csv` outputs it to a new file.

Now there is one caveat. The file is technically a .TXT file and not a .CSV file. It doesn't change anything if you open it manually, but I don't know your workflow so this could matter.